# Can you explain why I am losing internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

#### Problem

Here is the problem. I live in an apartment together with two of my roommates. Each of us lives in a separate room (see diagram: Mine is Blue, Room1 and Room2 are where my roommates live). There is a router wifi modem **R** in my room which is connected through the cable to another modem (which is the one that connects us all to the internet:)

Whenever somebody walks out of the **Room1** I lose internet connection on my laptop **L1** (ping freezes) no pages can be opened, everything stops working network wise. My android **A0** get also disconnected though it does not say network is unavailable, the network icon is working and shows a stable signal but I have no connection. The connection restores when somebody goes back to **Room1** and closes the door O_o I have ping, all is good as it was before.

I noticed that the door to **Room1** should be half-opened for connection to be lost.

#### Setup

My laptop **L1**
is connected to router via cable (not wifi), my **A0** android device is connected to router via wifi. My roommates in **Room1** and **Room2** use only our wifi network to connect to the internet. The roommate in **Room2** does not complain about his wifi connection being lost frequently while my connection is lost every single time somebody walks out of **Room1**.

Main modem is located two levels above and my wifi-modem (**R**) is connected to it with the cable which goes through the wall of my room outside the house. The cable stretches up and goes through the wall on the 3 floor where it is connected to the main modem. Wifi-modem sits behind a small sofa on the floor with antennas set vertically.

My laptop is connected to wifi-modem with a LAN cable all the time. My Android tablet is wirelessly connected to wifi-modem.
I use both Linux and Windows 8  and both oses lose connection as described above. So does Android tablet (hardware on my side should not be the issue).

What can be a possible reason for this strange behaviour (poltergeist is not an option) ?

[image]

Comment: I would find a store with no restocking/return fee and buy a new wifi access point/router and if that is not it return it and get your money back.  Since your laptop dies and it is hard wired it is most likely not a wi-fi issue and more like your access point or modem is dying.

Comment: But the wifi network does not disappear anywhere it is just I can't ping anything. Ok, I shall try to find another modem then.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is the cable running to your modem runs under the carpeting and who ever walks on that spot is causing the cables to break momentarily.

Comment: no, the cable as shown, is in my room and it does not stay under the carpet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for a very interesting question, even without the possibility of a poltergeist.

Let me summarise my understanding of your situation (please correct me if I'm wrong) before I offer some suggestions to isolate the cause (I can't be sure, without having physically looked at your setup, that something strange isn't going on).

In your room (the blue room) you have a wifi router connected to a broadband modem ("the one that connects us all to the internet") which establishes the internet connection from your internet service provider (ISP) via a cable connected to your telephone socket.  The router is connected to the modem, presumably, via a cable running from its (the router's) WAN port to the modem's LAN port, and also presumably the router contains the access point (AP) that broadcasts the wifi radio signal for the wireless network that you and your roommates connect to when online (this signal is actually picked up by an embedded device in your laptop's motherboard called a network interface card (NIC, or wireless adapter) - it acts as a wireless receiver of the radio signals.

You are saying that when the room 1 occupant walks out of their room (do they leave their door open or closed?) you have wifi loss on your laptop and also your Android phone, and generally the room 2 occupant is not affected.  You also say that when they walk back in and close the door your wifi connection is fine again (does this happen always when they do this, or most of the time, or only some times?)

You haven't given enough details, like what kind of modem you have (DSL, ADSL, cable?) and whether the modem is in the same room as the router (this is not indicated on your apartment plan, but I assuming this is the case), the position of the router in your room and in relation to the modem (which part of the room is it in, is the wireless antenna properly extended up or blocked by something else), whether the router antenna is omni-directional (the radio signal propagates in all directions from the source) or not, what kind of wifi software you have (Airport for Macs, or something else) and how old your NIC is, and whether the person occupying room 1 also has connection issues when they temporarily leave the room and come back.  With regards to the last question, it may be important for you and the room 1 occupant to find out what happens to their connection when they leave the room and come back (with and without closing the door).  Another question is whether the room 1 door is closed or open when its occupant walks out of or into the room and you have wifi loss.

The first link in the chain of your laptop's internet connection is provided by the router in your rooom, so I would focus on this first.  Don't worry about the modem, try and work backwards to the source (modem) from the router.  Presumably you are not connected to the router by an Ethernet cable (if you were connected by Ethernet then I don't think this could happen, at least not in the way you are describing) but only wirelessly.

1. First, use an Ethernet cable to physically connect your laptop to the router.  Provided your base internet connection via the modem is up you should be able to connect without any problems regardless of what the occupant of room 1 is doing - that should not affect a working Ethernet connection with your laptop and the router.  If you can do this, then you know it is the router and/or something related to the router link with your laptop.

I will assume that this test will be successful (since your room mate in room 2 seems to be unaffected by the issue and therefore there must be a stable internet connection coming from the modem to the router, otherwise you would all have connection issues).  If the test fails then it may be more serious and you may need to look at the router-modem-telephone socket link.

2. If the Ethernet test is successful then you can rule out the modem and focus on the router and the router-laptop link.  In this case, the fact that you can't ping the router during your connection loss indicates a potentially faulty NIC (the wireless receiver in your laptop).  You should **always** be able to ping your router when it's on even when there the modem connection is down.  Check the NIC, do a diagnostics test via the OS (if you are using OS X you can use the Network Utility tool from `/Applications/Utilities` or via the Assist Me button on the Network panel from System Preferences.  Why are you pinging `8.8.8.8`?  You should ping the router's private IP address (the default gateway), which is something like `192.168.0.3` - if you are using OS X or a Unix like OS you can find this out by running the terminal command `ifconfig en0` or `ipconfig ifaddr en0` ) in OS X you can also find this out by looking at your wifi connection properties on the Network panel from System Preferences or using the Network Utility app from `/Applications/Utilities`).  While doing all of this make sure that you have the room 1 occupant out of the room, which you say is the cause.
3. If none of the above, check that the router antenna is properly extended vertically and is at a right angle to the floor, not facing horizontally or downwards at the floor.  Standard consumer WRs have antennae which are not omni-directional but one-dimensional, i.e. they propagate the signal in one diretction or plane from the side of the antenna.  If your antenna is not properly vertical or is directed at a certain acute angle towards room 1, say the room 1 door, then the signal from the router to your laptop bounces off from the parts of the wall and corridor near the room 1 door and isn't properly picked up by your laptop's NIC.  By moving the router and pointing its antenna closer to your laptop, and trying different positions, you can figure out whether it's this or something else causing the problem.
4. Otherwise, check the signal strength of your wifi (you can do this by using the wifi's and/or the router's configuration/admin utility, ask your provider, they will guide you), and/or change the wifi channel.  Increase the wifi signal strength and/or the channel, and test this with the room 1 occupant walking out of and into their room, while online.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer, I shall try get more details. I have updated my question with a setup information and minor details for now.

Comment: @tasty My answer was based on your original description which to me indicated a wireless connection to your router.  You need to provide all the details.  Also you need to be a bit more precise in your description: "router wifi modem" is not a good description, "wifi router" is better.  Your wired connection is probably an Ethernet connection.  If your Ethernet goes out then it could be a cabling issue or a problem with your NIC, but you haven't said whether the connection loss from the person walking out is predictably regular or not.

Comment: @Keltari I don't know whether your comment "You are making this more complicated than this needs to be." is aimed at the poster or me, but surely if it was that simple the poster and his roommates could have figured it out by now, or even a call to the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this more complicated than this needs to be.

If your laptop's *wired* internet connection is cutting out and your Android is still connected to WiFi, then your internet connection is what is being flaky.  Remember, WiFi is the medium your Android is connected to the router, it has nothing to do with the internet connection itself.

If the door is *truly* related to the internet cutting out, then something on the router is loose.  A cable perhaps?

Check the router's WAN connection and cable modem for loose cables.

Comment: the roommate in Room2 does not complain about unstable internet connection. The problem occurs in my room only. I am unaware of Room1 though.

Comment: @tasty Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.  Just because he isnt complaining doesnt mean there isnt a problem.  Solving a problem requires finding the root cause.  Start at the source of your problem and work your way down.  The problem is internet connectivity, so start where the internet does.  Check your cable modem and router.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel like I need to post an answer here now.
I do not experience the issue described above anymore.

The problem was my **old power strip** which I used to connect my laptop and other electrical devices in a room. It was a rather big power strip with some additional sockets for the phone line even. This power strip somehow interfered with wifi communication and when I replaced it with a simple one, wifi became stable.

I have no idea of how a specific power strip can cause wifi disconnects, so I ruled out it from the start, but the electrician, who visited us, strongly advised to replace it.
Once I did it, everything was ok.